# Perl Error when requesting proxy to https site. AnyEvent status 596

Tags: perl, anyevent

when requesting through a proxy that supports https to https site. The error 'Reason' => 'ssl23_get_server_hello comes: unknown protocol', 'Status' => 596,

I use the AnyEvent library, I suspect that the problem with the connect request, but I cannot solve it at all, I will be very grateful for the hint.

```
use strict;
use utf8;
use Data::Dumper;

use AnyEvent::HTTP;
use MIME::Base64;
use AnyEvent::Connector;


my $cookies = {};
my $done = AnyEvent->condvar;

my $request_watcher = http_request(
    get => 'https://randomup.ru',
    (
        keepalive  => 1,
        persistent => 1,
        recurse    => 0,
        cookie_jar => $cookies,
        timeout    => 10,
        headers    => {
            'user-agent'      => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3445.2 Safari/537.36',
            'accept-encoding' => 'gzip',
            'Accept-Language'=> 'en-us,en;q=0.5',
            'Accept-Charset'=> 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
            'Proxy-Authorization' => 'Basic ' . encode_base64('XXX' . ':' . 'XXX'),
        },
    ),
    on_header => sub {
        print STDERR Dumper @_;

        return 1;
    },
    proxy => ['XX.XX.XX.XX', 8000, 'http'],
    sub {
        print STDERR Dumper @_;
        #$done->send;

    }
);
$done->recv();
```

suspect that the tcp_connect method is also needed, but I don’t understand how to configure it.

So proxy works for LWP

```
require LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(10);
$ua->proxy(['https', 'http'], 'http://XXX:NChD7r@XXX.XXX.38.67:8000');
# $ua->proxy(['https'], 'https://proxy:8080'); # Fails
# $ua->env_proxy; # This also fails.

my $response = $ua->get('https://randomup.ru');

if ($response->is_success) {
    print $response->decoded_content;  # or whatever
}
else {
    die $response->status_line;
}
```

Unfortunately, I can not write a full proxy, because it is paid. But if without him absolutely nothing, then I can write.

Comment: I noticed through wireshar. When you send without a proxy, the TLSv1.2 protocol is used. When using a TLSv1 proxy.

Comment: This is most likely a problem with your TLS library and your proxy. You will need to post the version of the TLS library, the version and name of your proxy, and maybe run the SSL connection setup in the most verbose mode possible there.

Comment: @Corion Hello, the LWP library works well.

require LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(10);
$ua->proxy('https', 'http://XXX:XXX@XXX:8000');

my $response = $ua->get('https://randomup.ru');

if ($response->is_success) {
    print $response->decoded_content;  # or whatever
}
else {
    die $response->status_line;
}

Comment: For LWP, you have `https` in your proxy configuration. For AnyEvent, you have `http` in your proxy configuration. Which one is it?

Comment: @Corion the proxy is exactly working, because it is currently used in another program

Comment: @Corion 
LWP without https, does not use a proxy for this scheme http, I do not know why. Judging by the wireshark, it immediately sends requests directly. Anyevent via https also fails to configure.

Comment: Please edit your question, add the working LWP code and then edit whether you are actually using a proxy or not. Your comments are confusing. If LWP does not use a proxy, why do you want AnyEvent to use a proxy?

Comment: @Corion
I'm not saying that LWP does not use a proxy. I say he ignores them if you choose http. The code LWP is working, but https.

Comment: If you have working code, please try to make your non-working code as similar to the working code as possible. Whatever remains as the difference is then likely the cause of the error. I don't know what works and what fails for you, so please [edit] your question and add what works and what fails for you.

Comment: @Corion, Done..

Comment: @Corion
Maybe you know how to configure https on anyevent? Maybe then everything will work.

Comment: From looking at the source code of `AnyEvent::HTTP`, the error code 596 occurs if ` $hdl->starttls ("connect")` fails (for example). So maybe you can debug AnyEvent::HTTP / AnyEvent::TLS there and reduce your problem from HTTP(s)+PROXY to TLS+PROXY or CONNECT through proxy